# Проблема с получением кук через расширение для Google Chrome, используя chrome.cookies.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь прочитать куки через chrome.cookies.get

```
function getCookiesQ(domain, name, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    });
}

function getCookies() {
    getCookiesQ("https://www.google.com", "APISID", function(id) {
    alert(id);
    });
}
```

В manifest.json прописаны нужные разрешения

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "cookies", "http://*.google.com/"]
```

Но при вызове функции появляются следующие ошибки:

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of
>   undefined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: No host permissions for cookies at url:
>   "https://www.google.com/".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты запрашиваешь разрешение на доступ к `http://*.google.com/`, а обращаешься к `https://www.google.com/`...  разная схема == разные ресурсы. Можно прописать в манифесте `http*://*.google.com/` или `*://*.google.com/` (насколько помню, `*` в схеме матчит только `http` и `https`), но лучше уточнить это в справке.

Comment: @yar85, делай ответом :)
Я не знаю, как я этого не заметил

Comment: Это нормально, мы же в основном с кодом работаем, вот глаз и замыливается на текстовую инфу. Вот буквально на днях, после работы я литерал объекта спутал с массивом, не различив фигурные скобки - сам от себя в шоке был :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что URL `https://www.google.com` (используемый в коде для чтения куки) не соответствует шаблону `http://*.google.com/`, указанному в манифесте. Отличается схема - а значит, это два разных URL.

Для того чтобы избегать подобных ситуаций, вполне допустимо использовать в `permissions` шаблоны вида `"*://*.google.com/"` - это не ужесточает проверку расширения при его публикации (главное чтобы TLD и SLD были указаны явно).

У звездочки вместо схемы, есть нюанс: она совпадает с `http` или `https`, но не совпадает с `file` или `ftp` (когда есть необходимость обращаться к URL с двумя последними схемами, это следует иметь в виду, в манифесте указывая для них отдельные шаблоны).